# What are 'File Create' participants in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, event-handling, listener

I tried to create a `README.md` file inside an empty directory in vscode and I got a text saying

> "Running 'File Create' participants..."

which I had to cancel after a while before seeing my file. It is probably a vscode issue but this is another story.

I also saw the following related setting in vscode:

```json
// Timeout in milliseconds after which file participants for create, rename, and delete are cancelled. Use `0` to disable participants.
  "files.participants.timeout": 60000,
```

My question is: What are Participants?

Does the above expression translate to "Running 'File Create' event handlers"? If yes, how does "Participants" differentiate from Handlers? (or is it more close to Observers/Listeners?)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658602/file-operations-taking-long-time-receiving-running-file-save-delete-create for some proposed fixes.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the feedback. My question was not on how to fix the issue. It was about the meaning of `File participants` and the difference from concepts like handlers or listeners.